# Logout logic is not working with basic authentication

Tags: spring, spring-security

This is my logout code. It is getting redirected to `logout.done` but, if I again go to `hello` I'm still able to access it.

```
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.httpBasic().and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/hello/**").hasRole("user")
    .and()
    .logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
    .logoutSuccessUrl("/logout.done").deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
    .invalidateHttpSession(true);
}
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: did you try adding `clearAuthentication(true)`? just after `.logout()` can add it like `..logout().clearAuthentication(true)..`

Comment: Basic authentication and logout don't work. As soon as you are logged out you will be logged in again as the client will probably send the basic header again. If you are using a js client make sure to rest the basic authentication header on the client as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code worked for me:

```
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.httpBasic().and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/hello/**").hasRole("user").and().formLogin().and()
    .httpBasic()
    .and()
    .logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
    .logoutSuccessUrl("/logout.done").deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
    .invalidateHttpSession(true).clearAuthentication(true);
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Add Spring security  and spefic controller

```
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.httpBasic().and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/hello/**").hasRole("user")
    .and()
    .logout()
    .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout").invalidateHttpSession(true).deleteCookies("JSESSIONID");
}

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/login" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView adminLogin(Model model,@RequestParam(value = "error", required = false) String error,
        @RequestParam(value = "logout", required = false) String logout, 
        @RequestParam(value = "expired", required = false) String expired,
        @RequestParam(value = "accessdenied", required = false) String accessdenied,
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    if (logout != null) {
        logger.info("logout application");
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(null);
        SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (auth != null){   
            new SecurityContextLogoutHandler().logout(request, response, auth);
        }
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        Enumeration<?> e = session.getAttributeNames();
        while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
            String attr = (String) e.nextElement();
            session.setAttribute(attr, null);
        }
        if (session != null) {
            session.removeAttribute(HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT_KEY);
            session.invalidate();
        }
        for (javax.servlet.http.Cookie cookie : request.getCookies()) {
            cookie.setMaxAge(0);
            cookie.setValue(null);
            cookie.setPath("/");
        }
        model.addAttribute(MESSAGE, "You have been logged out successfully.");
        model.addAttribute(SUCCESSMSG, true);
    }

    final ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.addObject("adminLogin", new AdminLogin());
    modelAndView.setViewName("login");
    return modelAndView;
```

}

Comment: I don't think there is a need for specifying controller as logout is already implemented in spring security. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: yes,I have mentioned spring security and manually how to logout and clear session,cookie etc